# Calculating index for projects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a Python project for my portfolio, It is allocating projects to students. For this, I am importing data from a file "student_Record.csv". The file has the student's name, last name, marks and 3 project preferences. I want to assign an index to each project before I assign the projects to the students. The index is calculated as Index(P)=50*(Number of Students that put P as 1st preference) + 25*(Number of students that put P as 2nd preference) + 1*(Number of students that put P as 3rd preference)

The sample data in the file looks like
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7cl.png)

I have done the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')

project_preferences = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get the student's preferences
    preferences = [row['Pref_1'], row['Pref_2'], row['Pref_3']]
    
    # Assign preference weights to projects
    for preference in preferences:
        project = int(preference)
        
        # Update the project's preference count
        if project not in project_preferences:
            project_preferences[project] = [0, 0, 0]
        project_preferences[project][preferences.index(preference)] += 1

# Calculate Wayne index for each project
wayne_index = {}
for project, preferences in project_preferences.items():
    wayne_index[project] = 50 * preferences[0] + 25 * preferences[1] + preferences[2]

# Print the Wayne index for each project
for project, index in wayne_index.items():
    print(f"Wayne index for Project {project}: {index}")
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: maybe? is it giving you answers that look right? If I'm reading this right, you want to calculate the count of each project in each of the 3 columns, and for each project, then calculate the index using your formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv('student_record.csv', skiprows=1)
    
    # Initialize the wayne_index dictionary
    wayne_index = {}
    
    # Calculate the wayne_index for each number
    for number in range(1, 101):
        count_Pref_1 = df['Pref_1'].value_counts().get(number, 0)
        count_Pref_2 = df['Pref_2'].value_counts().get(number, 0)
        count_Pref_3 = df['Pref_3'].value_counts().get(number, 0)
        wayne_index= (50 * count_Pref_1) + (25 * count_Pref_2) + count_Pref_3
        print(wayne_index)import pandas as pd
```

Comment: yup, looks 90% like what I suggested. I like the use of get to remove the try/excepts.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on the problem. Key note: avoid iterating over rows in a dataframe if you can.

1. read all projects by unioning the sets from all three columns. It doesn't tell you which projects had no answers though, so this would be better done with a projects table/df
2. for each project, calculate the count of it in each column (this has a try-except, as if the value_count is zero, then you'll get a key error)
3. calculate the value and update the dictionary

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
    projects = set(df['pref_1']).union(set(df['pref_2'])).union(set(df['pref_3']))
    wanye_index={}
    for project in projects:
        try:
            first_pref_count=df['pref_1'].value_counts()[project]
        except:
            first_pref_count=0 #need an except here incase the count is zero, and then a key error occurs
        try:
            second_pref_count=df['pref_2'].value_counts()[project]
        except:
            second_pref_count=0
        try:
            third_pref_count=df['pref_3'].value_counts()[project]
        except:
            third_pref_count=0
        wayne_index.update({project: ((50 * first_pref_count) + (25 * second_pref_count) + third_pref_count)})
    print("wayne index by project (project:index): ", wayne_index)
```